# Why is library 'resolv' prompted not to find this error

Tags: go

**this is my code**:

```
package main

import python3 "github.com/go-python/cpy3

func main() {
python3.Py_Initialize()
defer python3.Py_Finalize()
python3.PyRun_SimpleString("print('hello world')")
}
```

**The following problem arises after execution**:

`/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1 ld: library 'resolv' not found clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

**Here is my go env**:

`GO111MODULE="on" GOARCH="arm64"  GOBIN=""  GOCACHE="/Users/binzhang/Library/Caches/go-build" GOENV="/Users/binzhang/Library/Application Support/go/env" GOEXE="" GOEXPERIMENT="" GOFLAGS="" GOHOSTARCH="arm64" GOHOSTOS="darwin" GOINSECURE="" GOMODCACHE="/Users/binzhang/Code/Gostudy/pkg/mod" GONOPROXY="" GONOSUMDB="" GOOS="darwin" GOPATH="/Users/binzhang/Code/Gostudy" GOPRIVATE="" GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct" GOROOT="/usr/local/go" GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org" GOTMPDIR="" GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64" GOVCS="" GOVERSION="go1.20.1" GCCGO="gccgo" AR="ar" CC="clang" CXX="clang++" CGO_ENABLED="1" GOMOD="/dev/null" GOWORK="" CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g" CGO_CPPFLAGS="" CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g" CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g" CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g" PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config" GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/f0/t254fnjs2wg7krz7xc1zksg00000gn/T/go-build4109859426=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"\`

**This is my system env**:
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Users/binzhang/opt/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/pkgconfig`

***This problem has been bothering me for several days and I don't know how to solve it. I would appreciate it if anyone could help***
Excuse my poor English

I want to return to hello world

`hello world`

Comment: Check if the resolv library is installed on your system. You can do this by running the command ldconfig -p | grep resolv. If the library is not installed, you can install it using your package manager. For example, on Ubuntu, you can run sudo apt-get install libresolv1